# Simple regression coefficient manipulation.

Tags: regression, linear-regression

Show that

$$\hat{\beta_1}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^nx_i(y_i-\bar{y})}{\sum_{i=1}^nx_i(x_i-\bar{x})}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\bar{x})(y_i-\bar{y})}{\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\bar{x})^2}$$

I am learning simple linear regression and the text wants me to prove the above as an exercise. I am really just not sure where to begin. I don't have a solid grasp on how to simplify $\bar{x}$ and $\hat{x}$. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

\begin{align}\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\bar{x})(y_i-\bar{y})&=\sum_{i=1}^nx_i(y_i-\bar{y})-\sum_{i=1}^n\bar{x}(y_i-\bar{y}) \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^nx_i(y_i-\bar{y})-\bar{x}\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i-\bar{y})
\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^nx_i(y_i-\bar{y})-\bar{x}(0)
\\&= \sum_{i=1}^nx_i(y_i-\bar{y})\end{align}

Comment: Thank you! Could you clarify how you simplified sum(y_i - ybar) = 0?

Comment: $\sum_{i=1}^n y_i -\sum_{i=1}^n \bar{y}=\sum_{i=1}^n y_i -n \bar{y}=0$

Answer (score 0):

For $\sum (x_i - \bar x)^2$ note, that:

$\sum (x_i- \bar x)^2= \sum x_i^2 -2 \sum x_i \bar x + \sum \bar x^2 = \sum x_i^2 - 2 \bar x n \bar x + n \bar x^2 = \sum x_i^2 -n \bar x^2$

and

$\sum x_i(x_i-\bar x) = \sum (x_i^2-x_i \bar x) = \sum x_i^2 - \bar x \sum x_i = \sum x_i^2 - n \bar x^2$